# Why is a random forest regressor better than a random forest classifier when predicting a category?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, random-forest

I am building a model that recommends the optimal golf club based on data I have gathered. Since the model prediction should be a category, ie. a golf club, I would assume I would have to use a classifier algorithm. However, I have label encoded the types of golf clubs in an ordinal way from 1-14 (1 being the club with longer distance shots and 14 being the one for shortest shots) and have run both random forest regressor and classifier with scikit-learn and the regressor is more accurate. Why is this?

Comment: First, it sounds more like a regression problem. Second, how do you judge “better”?

Comment: The accuracy score of both differ by 4%. So it is not a big difference. However, looking at how to create a ml algorithm, it says that if the predicted output is a category a classification algorithm should be used. Hence I tried SVM, KNN, Random forest classification, decision tree classifier and NaivesBayes (all classification algorithm) however none give a better accuracy score that the random forest regressor.

Comment: How did you calculate accuracy for regression?

Comment: By using the method .score(X_test, y_test)

Answer (score 2):

From the comments:

> - How did you calculate accuracy for regression?
> - By using the method .score(X_test, y_test)

[RandomForestRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.score) and [RandomForestClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html?highlight=randomforest#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.score) return *completely different* metrics when you call the `score` functions. Regressor returns [coefficient of determination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) ($R^2$), while for classifier the accuracy. You *cannot* compare those numbers, it's comparing apples to oranges. There is also no way to calculate accuracy for a regression problem because it doesn't do classification while accuracy is a classification metric (a [poor one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312780/why-is-accuracy-not-the-best-measure-for-assessing-classification-models), by the way).

So the results you observed tell you nothing that allows you to tell that one of the approaches worked better than the another.

Comment: Ok this is a useful answer. Thanks! What other metric exist to analyse the performance of classifier algorithms?

Comment: @GUILLEDOMINGUEZ there are many metrics, but the basic question is if you want a classification or regression metric? If it’s ordinal regression then https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/9741/35989